# Bottom-right aligned spacebar

Tags: html, css, css-float, width, fixed

I can't figure out what's blocking here, or if it's just not possible. I wanted to put together what seemed like a simple design, right aligned sidebar with the content of the sidebar aligned in the bottom, the main content flowing freely but not going underneath the sidebar, yet I can't get it right. This is as close as I can get it, but I can't get the background to run along the whole height.

```css
.main_box {
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
    float:left;
    background-color: green;
}

.side_panel {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}

.bottom_nav {
    background-color: red;
    width: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_box">
            <div class="side_panel">
                <div class="bottom_nav">
                    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla posuere, nibh convallis tristique imperdiet, risus enim blandit felis, a semper mi arcu sit amet purus. Aliquam urna quam, venenatis et ligula ac, vestibulum efficitur diam. Integer vitae metus ac tellus consequat condimentum. Cras iaculis augue eget faucibus vehicula. Etiam facilisis metus ac sapien rutrum placerat. Nulla nibh enim, tincidunt ac suscipit vestibulum, tincidunt ac magna. Integer vestibulum, ligula sed accumsan faucibus, enim velit congue lorem, eget consequat eros est nec enim. Vestibulum ac gravida purus. Sed non rhoncus ante. Sed facilisis eros at risus feugiat laoreet. Aliquam imperdiet justo non velit luctus finibus. Proin eget finibus nulla, in congue nulla. Proin eget enim eget lorem tincidunt pellentesque. Suspendisse potenti. Morbi lacinia vehicula lacus id efficitur. Nunc fringilla libero augue, sed iaculis lorem efficitur nec.</p>
            <p>Sed vel feugiat enim, at bibendum ex. Mauris id commodo arcu, nec lacinia nulla. Donec rhoncus ex quis urna suscipit condimentum. Suspendisse ante purus, vulputate a lectus efficitur, bibendum dignissim ante. Aliquam nec mollis sapien, placerat hendrerit nisi. Nam at tempus nisl. Donec accumsan augue non mauris varius, eu accumsan neque ullamcorper. Aliquam mollis, orci at varius euismod, urna eros pulvinar massa, sit amet viverra nunc arcu a tortor. Nunc pulvinar non erat vel volutpat. Donec eu blandit arcu. Vivamus bibendum dolor arcu, ut fringilla ex tincidunt nec. Sed id placerat tortor. Curabitur non tellus sagittis, sodales est vitae, blandit justo.</p>
            </div>
```

Comment: top:0 to the fixed element?

Comment: @TemaniAfif No, it brings the content right back up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when using a `position:fixed` the element you will get removed from the normal flow making its parent element *empty* like it doesn't exist.

Consider the parent element to be fixed then place the content inside at the bottom:

```css
.main_box {
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
}

.side_panel {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.bottom_nav {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width:100%;
}

body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_box">
  <div class="side_panel">
    <div class="bottom_nav">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla posuere, nibh convallis tristique imperdiet, risus enim blandit felis, a semper mi arcu sit amet purus. Aliquam urna quam, venenatis et ligula ac, vestibulum efficitur diam. Integer vitae
    metus ac tellus consequat condimentum. Cras iaculis augue eget faucibus vehicula. Etiam facilisis metus ac sapien rutrum placerat. Nulla nibh enim, tincidunt ac suscipit vestibulum, tincidunt ac magna. Integer vestibulum, ligula sed accumsan faucibus,
    enim velit congue lorem, eget consequat eros est nec enim. Vestibulum ac gravida purus. Sed non rhoncus ante. Sed facilisis eros at risus feugiat laoreet. Aliquam imperdiet justo non velit luctus finibus. Proin eget finibus nulla, in congue nulla.
    Proin eget enim eget lorem tincidunt pellentesque. Suspendisse potenti. Morbi lacinia vehicula lacus id efficitur. Nunc fringilla libero augue, sed iaculis lorem efficitur nec.</p>
  <p>Sed vel feugiat enim, at bibendum ex. Mauris id commodo arcu, nec lacinia nulla. Donec rhoncus ex quis urna suscipit condimentum. Suspendisse ante purus, vulputate a lectus efficitur, bibendum dignissim ante. Aliquam nec mollis sapien, placerat hendrerit
    nisi. Nam at tempus nisl. Donec accumsan augue non mauris varius, eu accumsan neque ullamcorper. Aliquam mollis, orci at varius euismod, urna eros pulvinar massa, sit amet viverra nunc arcu a tortor. Nunc pulvinar non erat vel volutpat. Donec eu blandit
    arcu. Vivamus bibendum dolor arcu, ut fringilla ex tincidunt nec. Sed id placerat tortor. Curabitur non tellus sagittis, sodales est vitae, blandit justo.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Gawd, thanks! I was wondering why this blue element didn't show up now I get it, damn, so silly... thanks!